# Is the arithmetic function $\alpha$ , defined by $\alpha(n) = \sigma(n)^2$ , a multiplicative function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that $\sigma(n)$ is a multiplicative function and squaring it shouldn't change it from being multiplicative. However I am not sure how to show this generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, once you get your head around the definitions. But since you're a high school student, it's understandable that you may not have seen this kind of argument before.

If $n_1$ and $n_2$ are coprime, then $\sigma(n_1 n_2) = \sigma(n_1)\sigma(n_2)$, since $\sigma$ is multiplicative.

Therefore, if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are coprime, then
$$ \alpha(n_1n_2) = \sigma(n_1 n_2)^2 = \left( \sigma(n_1)\sigma(n_2) \right)^2= \sigma(n_1)^2\sigma(n_2)^2 = \alpha(n_1)\alpha(n_2),$$
so $\alpha$ is multiplicative too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Then if $\sigma(n)$ is multiplicative, we have $\sigma(n) = \sigma(ab) = \sigma(a) \sigma(b)$

Then $\alpha(n) = \sigma(n)^2 = \sigma(ab)^2 = \sigma(a)^2 \sigma(b)^2 = \alpha(a)\alpha(b) = \alpha(ab)$ which shows that $\alpha(n)$ is also multiplicative.